# Formula involving Wigner's 3j symbols and integration over irreducible representations of SU(2)

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, physics, haar-measure

In some calculations, I saw the following formula

$$\int_{\mathrm{SU}(2)}\,\mathrm{d}g\,D^{j_{1}}_{m_{1}n_{1}}(g)D^{j_{2}}_{m_{2}n_{2}}(g)D^{j_{3}}_{m_{3}n_{3}}(g)=(-1)^{j_{1}+j_{2}+j_{3}}\begin{pmatrix}j_{1} & j_{2} & j_{3}\\m_{1} & m_{2} & m_{3}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}j_{1} & j_{2} & j_{3}\\n_{1} & n_{2} & n_{3}\end{pmatrix}$$

where $\mathrm{d}g$ denotes the (normalized) Haar measure on $SU(2)$and where $D^{j}$ denote Wigner's D-matrices, i.e. the unitary irreducible representation of $SU(2)$ of dimension $2j+1$. The matrix-looking objects on the right hand side denote [Wigner's 3j symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-j_symbol), which are related to the Clebsch-Gordon coefficients.

The formula appears in the mathematical derivation of the so-called "Ponzano-Regge model" of 3d Euclidean Quantum Gravity. I am wondering how this formula is derived. Furthermore, I have seen in different sources that sometimes the sign factor in front is missing. Another source is mentioning that this formula is only true if $\vert j_{2}-j_{3}\vert\leq j_{1}\leq j_{2}+j_{3}$. So all in all I become very confused and would like to know whether this formula is correct and which assumptions are needed. Does maybe someone also have some reference on it?

Comment: The sign factor is probably convention (certainly for the related Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, there are different conventions). Since these symbols connect different angular momentum states, and the phases of states can be chosen at will, that implies that also different conventions for the coefficients are possible.

Comment: The sign convention I know about would affect both 3j symbols in the same way and then would not matter for the product...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker - hm, yes, but if the $D$-matrix convention is changed - there are three of those ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a fully worked-out derivation in these [lecture notes.](http://www.hep.caltech.edu/~fcp/physics/quantumMechanics/angularMomentum/angularMomentum.pdf) The formula you are looking for is equation (404), written in terms of the Wigner (small)-$d$ matrix. The relationship to the (large)-$D$ matrix goes via the Euler angle parameterization,
$$D^{j}_{mm'}(\psi,\theta,\phi)=e^{-im\psi-im'\phi}d^{j}_{mm'}(\theta).$$
The integration over SU(2) with the Haar measure is given in terms of Euler angles by
$$U(\psi,\theta,\phi)=\exp(-i(\psi/2)\sigma_1)\exp(-i(\theta/2)\sigma_2)\exp(-i(\phi/2)\sigma_3,$$
$$\int_{\rm{SU}(2)}f(U)\,dU=\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}d\psi\int_0^\pi\sin\theta d\theta\int_0^{4\pi}d\phi\, f[U(\psi,\theta,\phi)].$$

So the desired integral over a product of three $D$-matrices vanishes unless $m_1+m_2+m_3=0=n_1+n_2+n_3$. In that case the integrations over $\psi$ and $\phi$ give a factor $8\pi$, what remains is the integration over $\theta$. Eq. (404) in the lecture notes shows how that is related to the product of $3j$-symbols,
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi d\theta\,d^{j_1}_{m_1n_1}d^{j_2}_{m_2n_2}d^{j_3}_{m_3n_3}=\begin{pmatrix}j_{1} & j_{2} & j_{3}\\m_{1} & m_{2} & m_{3}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}j_{1} & j_{2} & j_{3}\\n_{1} & n_{2} & n_{3}\end{pmatrix}.$$
Both sides of the equation are equal to zero unless the $j$'s satisfy the triangle inequality, $\vert j_{2}-j_{3}\vert\leq j_{1}\leq j_{2}+j_{3}$.

This formula differs from the one in the OP by a factor $(-1)^{j_1+j_2+j_3}$. As a test, I evaluated both sides of the equation with Mathematica, for $j_1=2$, $j_3=3$, $j_4=4$, $m_1=n_1=1$, $m_2=n_2=-1$, $m_3=n_3=0$, and find $5/126$, without a minus sign.

(1/2)*Integrate[
  WignerD[{2, 1, 1}, theta]*WignerD[{3, -1, -1}, theta]*
   WignerD[{4, 0, 0}, theta]*Sin[theta], {theta, 0, Pi}]

ThreeJSymbol[{2, 1}, {3, -1}, {4, 0}]*
ThreeJSymbol[{2, 1}, {3, -1}, {4, 0}]